# Can't get last int from .txt file

Tags: c++, text-files, ifstream, eof

My Issue involves reading integers from a text file, saving them to an array and then copying the array to a new .txt file.

So there is a file "`krol.txt`"

```
2 4
3 7
3 13
2 4
3 1
```

The problem is that it never ever save the last '1' from the input .txt file. I have no idea why. I think its about EOF on last character in file but why it works like that? Can anyone help me?

This is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    ofstream outFile;
    ifstream fin;
    fin.open("krol.txt");
    int l=0;
    char ch;

    while (fin.good()) {
        fin.get(ch);

        if(ch=='\n') l++;
    }
    fin.close();

    fin.open("krol.txt");
    int temp[l][2];
    int savel=l;
    l=0;
    int i=0;

    while (fin >> (temp[l][i])) {
        i++;
        if(i==2) { 
                i=0;
                l++;
        }
    }

    outFile.open("save.txt");

    for (int i=0, j=0;j<savel;i++) {
        if (i==2) {
            i=0; j++;
        }
        outFile << temp[j][i];
    }

    outFile.close();
    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Does this *really* compile? `int temp[l][2];` (that's `l` a non-`const` `int` variable, not a number).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This saves all the numbers just fine. The problem is, it stores additional numbers in `save.txt`.

With

```
while (fin.good()){
...
}
```

you count the last line twice. This gives you two additional *uninitialized* `int`s. These two `int`s can show up as any integer.

I see two problems. Your first loop to get the number of lines should be more like

```
while (fin.get(ch)){
    if (ch == '\n')
        l++;
}
```

If the last line doesn't have a final `\n`, you could end with one line less than you need.

And the output loop could be simplified to

```
for (int j = 0; j < savel; j++){
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
        outFile << temp[j][i] << ' ';
}
```

And finally, if you use [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b), you should consider using `std::vector` instead of plain arrays. Then you don't need to preallocate your array and can read the file in just one pass.

Comment: save.txt goes crazy and save '2 4 3 7 3 13 2 4 3 1 2293083 0 '. what are 2 last numbers stand for? What the heck is that.

Answer (score 0):

There might be 4 '\n' chars in that file have you considered that?